# Only gets Metadata from GridFS in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, metadata

i don't want to get the inputstream of an GridFSDBFile in java. i only want to get the metadata.

```
DBCollection fsFilesCollection = mongoOperations.getCollection("fs.files");
DBObject result = fsFilesCollection.findOne(query.getIdObject());
```

Is there a better solution to do that?

One Problem ist, that i get a DBObject-Object as result for the first query.
If i send this query again, findOne resturns a GridFSDBFile-Object !??

My dirty Workaround is

```
if (result != null) {
    if (result instanceof GridFSDBFile) {
            return new FSGridMetaData((GridFSDBFile) result);
    } else {
            return new FSGridMetaData(result);
    }
}
```

!FSGridMetaData is my own object!